# HCL ME Y2 Tablet showing red screen on startup

Tags: tablet

On pressing the power button, usually the tablet shows a black screen, and then it starts. But now, it's just showing a ***red*** screen; it's stuck there. What is the cause behind this problem? Is there any solution for it, going to the service center being the last refuge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a factory reset.

1. Turn off device.
2. Hold buttons volume up and power key.
3. Wait for Red screen to appear.
4. Release the buttons.
5. Navigate using volume control and confirm using power key.
6. Choose Factory Reset.
7. Choose Reboot.

If this doesn't work then I'd say it's time for repair or replacement.